# node-gyp rebuild failure : ares.h file not found

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I have recently updated the nodejs version on my system from 0.10.37 to 0.12.5, after the upgrade node-gyp rebuild is failing for one of the npm package I use. It gives an error "ares.h" file not found.

This is the error I get while building it

```
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ancillary/src/ancillary.o
In file included from ../src/ancillary.cc:4:
In file included from /Users//.node-gyp/0.12.2/src/stream_wrap.h:25:
/Users//.node-gyp/0.12.2/src/env.h:25:10: fatal error: 'ares.h' file not found
#include "ares.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/ancillary/src/ancillary.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users//src/node-ancillary
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

When I do npm version, I see

```
{ npm: '2.12.0',
  http_parser: '2.3',
  modules: '14',
  node: '0.12.2',
  openssl: '1.0.1m',
  uv: '1.4.2-node1',
  v8: '3.28.73',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

With the older nodejs version I used to get

```
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.37',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.36',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1l',
  npm: '1.4.28' }
```

With the newer version I do not see the ares package in npm version result, I am suspecting it to be an issue with the build failure.

**How can I get rid of the above mentioned build error ?**

Comment: It looks like the developer of the `ancillary` module hasn't worked on it [for quite some time](https://github.com/VanCoding/node-ancillary/issues/7#issuecomment-103560009), so chances are that you won't be able to get it working in Node 0.12

Comment: I have made some changes in the code myself in the ancillary code for 0.12, but its not getting build. This error has nothing to do with my changes. nodejs stream_wrap is throwing the error.